# MSBuild through GitHub action on dedicated drive

Tags: github, msbuild, yaml, github-actions, github-for-windows

I'm trying to setup a GitHub workflow to compile msbuild on self-hosted windows agent.

On my self-hosted agent the build needs to be run on specified dedicated drive.

My action workflow as follows,

```yaml
name: Windows_Action
on:
  push:
    branches: 
    - master 
jobs:
  build-on-windows:
    runs-on:  [self-windows]
    env:
      DRIVE: P:\
      DEV_TOOL_PATH: C:\DevTools\
      NUGUT_TOOL_PATH: C:\DevTools\project-2022\
      PRJ_VERSION: 1.12.0.1
   
    steps:
      - uses: code-actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: MS build
        shell: cmd
        run: |
          copy E:\ram.k\packages\packagebug.vsix $GITHUB_WORKSPACE\Package.vsix
          IF EXIST "$DRIVE" (
          subst $DRIVE /d
          ) 
          IF NOT EXIST "$DRIVE%" (
          subst $DRIVE% "$GITHUB_WORKSPACE"
          )
          "$DEV_TOOL_PATH\VSIXBrander.exe" "$DRIVE\ms-tools-core\src\network.VisualStudio.VsixSetup\source.extension.vsixmanifest" "$PRJ_VERSION"
          call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
          "$NUGUT_TOOL_PATH\nuget.exe" restore "$DRIVE\ms-tools-core\src\network.VisualStudio.sln"
          "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" "/t:restore" "$DRIVE\ms-tools-core\src\network.VisualStudio.sln"
          "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "$DRIVE\ms-tools-core\src\network.VisualStudio.sln" /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployExtension=False
```

**Action Error:-**

```
 The system cannot find the path specified.
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.2.2
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.2.1+52cd2da31 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: $DRIVE\ms-tools-core\src\network.VisualStudio.sln
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Whats wrong in my workflow yaml? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try with `echo $DRIVE` whether the variable exists?

Comment: `"$DRIVE"` says - `The system cannot find the path specified.`. Actually i'm trying to substitute the complete `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE` into separate drive `P:\`

Comment: And what says `ls P:`?

Comment: GitHub workspace substitute to `P:` didn't work.